# CSS3 Rotate from 0 to 90 then 90 to 180

Tags: css, animation

I have an object rotating 360 degrees using CSS3's rotate animation.  However, the code (linked below) rotates the image 360 degrees then repeats the same animation.

I want to rotate it 360 degrees, pause every 90 degress and have infinite rotating.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
.image {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
-webkit-animation:spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
-moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Here is a [JSFiddle for the project](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Ugc5g/)

Comment: Were you wanting it to stop for a duration after each 90 degree rotation

Comment: Not necessarily, especially if I have ease-in-out

Comment: @CodyGuldner comment above :)

Comment: Here's another jsfiddle that i've tried working with: http://jsfiddle.net/julien/rukC6/

Comment: So you still want to do a 360?

Comment: @MatthewR. Yeah, it'll still do a 360, it'll go:

0-90, 90-180, 180-270 then 270-360

Comment: SO you want to rotate it 360 degrees, pause every 90 degress and stop rotating after one iteration?

Comment: @stackErr Nearly, I want to rotate it 360 degrees, pause every 90 degress and infinite rotating.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add that in? Will be easier for other people to help you

Comment: @DavidIngledow Updated my answer to your request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add additional points in your keyframe:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rukC6/1/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
  25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
  45% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
  75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.animation-rotate {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help with this, thought that I would just let you know that I made this loading screen with it. [Here's the link to Vine](https://vine.co/v/hMYQQa3nU0H)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want it to stop after it rotates just remove the infinite modifier:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/30/

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s ease-in-out; // No more infinite
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear;
    animation:spin 4s linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin { 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

If you want to stop the animation at the increments it is a little harder:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/31/

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform:rotate(0deg); }
    25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform:rotate(90deg); }
    25.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform:rotate(90deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); transform:rotate(180deg); }
    50.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); transform:rotate(180deg); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); transform:rotate(270deg); }
    75.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); transform:rotate(270deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform:rotate(0deg); }
    25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform:rotate(90deg); }
    25.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform:rotate(90deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); transform:rotate(180deg); }
    50.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); transform:rotate(180deg); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); transform:rotate(270deg); }
    75.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); transform:rotate(270deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin { 
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform:rotate(0deg); }
    25% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform:rotate(90deg); }
    25.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); transform:rotate(90deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); transform:rotate(180deg); }
    50.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); transform:rotate(180deg); }
    75% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); transform:rotate(270deg); }
    75.5% { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); transform:rotate(270deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: Nearly, I want to rotate it 360 degrees, pause every 90 degress and infinite rotating.